# How to ignore "remote" validation for an input field using jQuery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to ignore a "remote" validation property for a form using jQuery validation plugin, so I can enable it when the form is submitted instead of an onBlur of a field. I have the following code, but am getting a syntax error. How can I fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
        $("#checkNameForm").validate( {
        "onkeyup":false,
        "rules":{
            "Name":{
                "required":true,
                "minlength":5,
                "maxlength":10,
                "remote":"\/abc\/def\/checkname"
            }
        },
        "messages":{
            "Name":{
                "required":"Please enter a Name.",
                "remote":"Name is already in use."
            }
        },
        "ignore":"input[
            remote
        ]   ",
        success:function(label) {
             label.addClass("success"); 
        },
        "validClass":"success"
    } ); 
});
```

Comment: what is the syntax error? The "ignore":"input[
            remote
        ]   ", looks off at first glance.

Comment: The syntax error is SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]  

"ignore":"input[

Comment: Maybe get rid of the line break after input[

Comment: trimming that line helps:  "ignore": "input[remote]",  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/LMP5W/)

Comment: ok.. I will try trimming it.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having line breaks inside of the ignore option is the issue:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/LMP5W/2)

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
        $("#checkNameForm").validate( {
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            "Name": {
                "required":true,
                "minlength":5,
                "maxlength":10,
                "remote":"\/abc\/def\/checkname"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "Name": {
                "required":"Please enter a Name.",
                "remote":"Name is already in use."
            }
        },
        ignore: "input[remote]",
        success: function(label) {
            label.addClass("success"); 
        },
        "validClass":"success"
    } ); 
});
```

Comment: I see the syntax is right now, but the plugin is not ignoring the input. It is still validating it. Do you know why?

Comment: remote is a property in JS validation plugin. By setting that we state that the validation plugin needs to execute an AJAX call. http://jsfiddle.net/MRxPT/

Comment: the ignore option should use a selector that would match the remote fields, then it will filter them out. Add a "remote" class to each, then use *ignore: ".remote"*.

Comment: hmm.. I wanted to specify the ignore property in such a way that it should ignore the remote validation, but later in an onclick event, I should be able to invoke it in a submitHandler

Comment: sounds like a different question... Please accept this answer for the current question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this easier way to remove a remote validation from an element:
`$('#myfield').rules('remove', 'remote');`